# How to redirect logs to STDOUT in Snap framework?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

Logs are written in the Snap web framework to `access.log` and errors to `error.log`. Is there a way to redirect outputs to `STDOUT` and errors to `STDERR`?